# Erlang dialyzer The created fun has no local return

Tags: erlang, static-analysis

I run dialyzer for my project. I got:

```
test.erl:97: The created fun has no local return
```

In 97 line i have:

```
    List = lists:filter(fun(X) ->
                               {_, _, SomeBoolFlag} = X,
                               SomeBoolFlag == false
                        end,
                TestList)
```

What's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Using only the provided code I cannot reproduce this warning. Please provide more context.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems `dialyzer` have found that `TestList` can contain something other than `{_, _, SomeBoolFlag}` tuples.

And also you can simplify this code a bit:

```
List = lists:filter(fun({_, _, Flag}) -> not Flag end, TestList)
```

or:

```
List = [Item || Item={_, _, false} <- TestList]
```